# How to add number from form in child component to array of numbers in parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to add a value from a textfield in a childcomponent (AddNum.js) to a array of numbers in the parent component (App.js).

Therefor I created in the parent component a usestate hook 'setValuesList':

```
const [valuesList, setValuesList] = useState([]);
```

Then I pass the hook to the childcomponent like this:

```
<AddNum valuesList={valuesList} setValuesList={setValuesList} />
```

My childcomponent looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const AddNum = ({ valuesList, setValuesList }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const addNumber = (value) => {
    const number = parseInt(value);
    setValuesList([...valuesList, number]);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={addNumber}>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      ></input>
      <button>Add Number</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default AddNum;
```

However, when I console log 'valuesList' in the parent component, and add a number through the form, I get an empty array:

```
[]
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

my repository is at:

https://github.com/acandael/add-to-list

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: Can you make a sandbox? [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq)

Comment: I have a repository, is that fine too?
https://github.com/acandael/add-to-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to the `onSubmit` handler will the `event`. The current implementation of the function `addNumber` that is passed as the submit handler to the form is completely incorrect.

**Solution** create a new submit handler function and to prevent the default form submit behavior call `event.preventDefault()` then do all the adding number logic.

```js
const AddNum = ({ valuesList, setValuesList }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const addNumber = (value) => {
    const number = parseInt(value, 10);
    setValuesList(prev => [...prev, number]);
  };

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    addNumber(value)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      ></input>
      <button>Add Number</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Working demo in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-snowflake-ue1nq?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import AddNum from './AddNum';

const App = () => {
  // do not write it like this     
  // const { valuesList, setValuesList } = useState([]);

  const [ valuesList, setValuesList ] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log(valuesList);
  }, [valuesList])

  return (
    <div>
      {<AddNum valuesList={valuesList} setValuesList={setValuesList} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

If you console.log outside useEffect it will always have the initial value, you need to get it inside useEffect and pass valuesList as dependency

Comment: useState was not well used =>   const [valuesList, setValuesList] = useState([]);  See the edited answer

Comment: I forgot to update my repository. I'm using
const [valuesList, setValuesList] = useState([]);
But I still have the same problem

Comment: well I tried your repo and it's working if you want to override form behaviour see subashMahapatra answer below